I'm using Angular 17 and wanted to use ngx-owl-carousel but having this issue,
The error
`TypeError: e.animate is not a function
at xc._triggerWebAnimation (/node_modules/@angular/animations/fesm2022/browser.mjs:4027:20)
at xc._buildPlayer (/node_modules/@angular/animations/fesm2022/browser.mjs:3999:27)
at xc.init (/node_modules/@angular/animations/fesm2022/browser.mjs:3991:10)
at player (/node_modules/@angular/animations/fesm2022/animations.mjs:1354:43)
at Array.forEach ()
at Bs.init (/node_modules/@angular/animations/fesm2022/animations.mjs:1354:18)
at Bs.play (/node_modules/@angular/animations/fesm2022/animations.mjs:1377:12)
at Gs.play (/node_modules/@angular/animations/fesm2022/browser.mjs:3610:34)
at player (/node_modules/@angular/animations/fesm2022/browser.mjs:3415:14)
at Array.forEach ()
Node.js v18.16.0`
The Ts File
import { Component, ElementRef, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { CarouselModule, OwlOptions } from 'ngx-owl-carousel-o';
import { AnalyticsService } from '../../../analyticsService.service';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { dataModule } from '../../../assets/data';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-project',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule, CarouselModule, BrowserAnimationsModule],
  templateUrl: './project.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./project.component.scss']
})
export class ProjectComponent {
  customOptions: OwlOptions = {
    loop: true,
    mouseDrag: true,
    touchDrag: true,
    pullDrag: false,
    navSpeed: 700,
    items: 1,
    autoplay: true,
    autoplayTimeout:3000
  };
    @ViewChild('imgContainer') imgContainer: ElementRef | any;

data = dataModule
slide: string = '';
  constructor(
    public analyticsService: AnalyticsService
  ) { }

debug(){

  this.imgContainer.nativeElement.scroll({
    top: this.imgContainer.nativeElement.scrollHeight,
    left: 0,
    behavior: 'smooth',    
  });
}

}


this is the version in package.json
   "@angular/animations": "^17.3.0",
